# Merge/synonymize [chararray] and [char-array]

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request

These two tags, [chararray](/questions/tagged/chararray) and [char-array](/questions/tagged/char-array), are the same thing, yet the tags link to two different sets of questions. Can these be merged and/or be given a synonym relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed:  [chararray](/questions/tagged/chararray) --> [char-array](/questions/tagged/char-array)