# Remove or reduce restrictions from tag synonym submission process

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, privileges

According to [the FAQ on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) synonymizing tags is an approved process, much like suggesting edits/voting to close/etc.:

> When a tag synonym reaches a vote score of 4, it is accepted and
>   becomes active. If a tag synonym reaches a vote score of -2 it is
>   deleted.

When this synonym acceptance voting is in-process, anyone can *see* the number of votes for/against the synonym on the tag info page (though I myself do not have enough reputation to vote). This makes sense to me, like many of the other mod-like privileges.

However, if I have the ability to suggest edits and tag wikis/excerpts, why not also have the ability to suggest a synonym relationship between two or more tags? I have [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141707/179372) [multiple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141224/179372) [merges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141119/179372) on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139044/179372), but I don't know why I (or anyone else) should have to go through these hoops. (<sub>I might also add that doing so gives someone else the credit for the synonymization, which prevents me from earning [this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1224/synonymizer).</sub>)

Also, from the synonym page of any tag, there is a rule stating you must have a tag score of 5 or more to vote on **or** suggest a synonym:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms.

Many of the tags I see as being able to be merged have a very small number of questions attached to them (with this likely being the reason it should be merged with something else). The above rule makes it that much more difficult to push through a legitimate merge. I think I understand the point behind this: `If we are going to push this change through, then we want those most familiar with the tag to make that judgement.`.

However, I don't feel that this is always appropriate. Perhaps the score of 5+ for a tag should apply only to higher volume tags? But since that might be hard to define, maybe we really ought to just do away with the whole rule altogether as well.

**Bottom line: Since it is already left to a democratic process anyways, then why not allow me to make the suggestion and let *those who can* approve or deny as they see fit?**

---

Footnote:

For the record, I just earned the privilege (sort of) to suggest synonyms, but alas, I don't have enough points to suggest any of those I listed above.

Comment: I'm sorry to burst your bubble, but 2,500 rep isn't nearly enough to suggest a tag synonym. You also need a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag.

Comment: @dennis Yes, I understand that (and I'll update the question), but oftentimes the plausible synonyms I see are for tags with only a handful of questions related to it, thereby making it difficult to get to that level.

Comment: `</sarcasm>`​​​

Comment: @Dennis Wasted on me, I'm afraid. <facepalm>

Comment: The system just doesn't work. I have 10 times the rep required to suggest a synonym, but still lack the 5 upvotes on most suggested tags, so I can't vote. Going over there right now, I think the first tag "import" and "imports" could reasonably be synonyms, but - surprise - I haven't posted anything tagged "import" so no vote.

Comment: @Gaffi: I'm not sure that your solution is the best one, but the community tag synonym creation process is less than ideal.

Comment: @TartLevee What else might your suggest then? I'm open to options.

Comment: Related: [Can we allow 7.5K users  to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211) and 900 zillion duplicates. The community *strongly* supports a reform of the tag synonym system.